# Add extra row before the first element in each partition inside RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have at least two partitions in spark RDD and each partition represents sparse matrix. I also have row count, column count and none zero value counts of each matrix. Now, how do i add these three value for each matrix as a extra new row before the first element of the respective partitions in RDD?

Comment: Some code will go a long way to showing what you have tried and where you are stuck and need help with.

Comment: Please post the code sample as well what you have tried so far and where you stucked.

Comment: I dont have any code ready! I have already calculated the row, column and none zero value count for each partition but main problem is how to add those value as a row to respective partitions(as a first row or element of the partition).

I have partitions in one RDD thats it, I dont know what to do after that

Comment: Please provide a sample  input sparse matrix and expected  output

Comment: I have one List which contains row count for each partition and other for column count. Each partition has data like this: 101 1 31 1 14 1 15 1 102 1 (each row in partition is like this )  

And I have to add extra data(which is one row) before the first element of each partition